# Are all dependencies of a class loaded by the same classloader?

Tags: java, class, tomcat, web-applications, classloader

- In my `/tomcat/lib` dir I have class `SharedClass` (which is thus shared with all web apps).
- In my web app's `WEB-INF/lib` I have class `LocalClass`.
- `SharedClass` has a reference to `LocalClass`.

In my web app I try to create an instance of `SharedClass` but it fails with the message:

> NoClassDefFoundError: LocalClass.

Since `SharedClass` is shared and `LocalClass` is local to my web app I was hoping it would work, but it doesn't.

My suspicion is that `SharedClass` is loaded by the Tomcat parent classloader and `LocalClass` is loaded by the Web App classloader.  Since `SharedClass` was loaded by the parent, I assume that all of its dependencies must also be loaded by the parent.  Thus, the parent can't find `LocalClass` and it throws the Error.

Does this make sense?  Is there any way around this (without writing my own classloader)?

Comment: After all of the edits, it appears that `SharedClass` has a direct reference it `LocalClass`. In which case, the context classloader trick that I showed won't work, and you need to package the JARs together.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, once `SharedClass` is loaded by the Parent Classloader it is "owned" by that classloader.  Thus, any other classes it references, even if they aren't loaded until way later (e.g. when a method is invoked) will still be loaded by Parent and Web App Classloader will never have a chance to load them?  Is this true, if I use reflection to load the dependent class as well?

Comment: `X` is only an instance of `X` if `X.class.getClassLoader() == X.class.getClassLoader()`. The parent ClassLoader cannot resolve types in the child ClassLoaders and even if it could, it could only see one of them. _Be thankful Tomcat doesn't support parent-last ClassLoaders - that's a whole other bundle of bugs._

Comment: @dough: no. SharedClass is loaded by the Tomcat classloader, and LocalClass is not accessible to this class loader: it's not in the Tomcat classpath.

Comment: @dough - Simple reflection won't work for the reason that *JB Nizet* said. You couldload the class with the context classloader, and then use reflection to invoke methods on it. **But this is a really bad idea**.

Comment: Please describe what you're actually trying to accomplish, because there's almost certainly an easier way, one that doesn't violate the application isolation that Tomcat works so hard to ensure..

Comment: @dough - #1, with #2 as a distant second (because, really, the app should be self-contained). Also, see the edit I made to my post.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment but here are the options @parsifal is referring to: 1. copy the `SharedClass` to WEB-INF/lib 2. copy `LocalClass` to tomcat/lib. 3. Use reflection in `SharedClass`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ClassLoaders are hierarchical. A class loader has a parent, and sees the classes of its parent. The reverse is not true. So a class loaded by the webapp's classloader has access to the classes loaded by the common Tomcat classloader (its parent), which has access to the JRE classes (the parent of Tomcat's classloader).

See [the Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) and the [ClassLoader javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

This does make sense, and it's the way that Tomcat is able to isolate applications. More information can be found here: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html

There are very few valid reasons for a shared class to load an application class or create an instance of an application class. For the rare cases where you need to do this, you can call `Thread.getCurrentThread().getContextClassloader()`.

---

Edit: I feel like I'm handing a LOX-soaked briquette to someone who wants to start a campfire, so here are the reasons why *it's a bad idea to load an application class from the shared classloader*.

The immediate problem is that you haven't actually loaded the class into the shared classloader, so you can't easily manipulate the objects that you create. Instead, you need to use reflection to invoke methods, which is going to make your code a mess.

But the worse problem is that, if your `SharedClass` instances maintain a reference to instances of `LocalClass`, those references will prevent Tomcat from undeploying the application. Actually, it will claim to undeploy, but there will still be pieces of the old application living in the permgen until those references are collected, and that often leads to permgen exhaustion.

So, while the context classloader is a useful tool -- and should be the *only* way that you access classpath resources -- it's a tool that can easily cause things to blow up.

Comment: It's not an unusual situation. I have an external dependency (ehcache) as a tomcat shared dependency, but that dependency relies on other dependencies (slf4j, etc). My only option is to move the transitive dependencies to shared directory too. Do you have a better suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In normal Java applications when a classloader is asked to load a class it forst delegates the request to it's parent class loader and then loads it if parent class loaders cannot find the requested class.

For web application servers this slightly differs. There are generally different class loader for each web app deployed in a web application server like tomcat. For Tomcat it looks like below -

[image]

So for web apps class loading resource happens in following order -

1. Bootstrap classes of your JVM (Core java classes)
2. /WEB-INF/classes of your web application
3. /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application
4. System class loader classes (Tomcat / Classpath specific classes)
5. Common class loader classes (classes common to all web apps)

But note if web application class loader is configured with `delegate="true"` then order is changed -

1. Bootstrap classes of your JVM (Core java classes)
2. System class loader classes (Tomcat / Classpath specific classes)
3. Common class loader classes  (classes common to all web apps)
4. /WEB-INF/classes of your web application
5. /WEB-INF/lib/*.jar of your web application

For more details you can check Apache Tomcat's [Class Loader HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html) page.